# Apparently matching strings not matching in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 database servers. One of them is running Postgres from a point in time base backup. Both report the client_encoding as UTF8.

I can query the primary database fine but when I query for a matching record on the backup database I get no results. I've tried crafting a *like* query to find any differences (see results below).

```
marketplace=> select email from listed_user where email = 'ted@mail.com';
email
-------
(0 rows)

marketplace=> select email from listed_user where email like '%ted@mail.com';
email
-----------------------
ted@mail.com
(1 row)

marketplace=> select email from listed_user where email like 'ted@mail.com%';
email
-----------------------
ted@mail.com
(1 row)
```

I tried performing a pg_dump on the table and inspecting the resulting file for hidden characters but didn't find any right off.

I'd guess an unprintable character or encoding issue but have yet to be able to determine the root cause.

Comment: Is the column `email` indexed? If so, you should [recreate the index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html).

Comment: Interesting... You can inspect the underyling byte sequence using `convert_to(email, 'UTF8')`, though I can't think of any way to explain this with unprintable characters. Take a look at the `EXPLAIN` output for each query; if the equality check is doing an index lookup, and the `LIKE` queries are performing a table scan, then you've probably got a corrupted index.

Comment: That was a _fun_ learning experience. Both @klin & nick-barnes were right on in seeing this as an index issue. Explain showed that an index was being used and attempting a reindex showed that it had become corrupted. I believe the root cause for my pain was my improper use of pg_ctl (on Mac) when I should have been using launchctl. I believe that launchtcl restarted postgres after I thought I had stopped it with pg_ctl and corrupted the backup as I restored it. Lesson learned - thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue...